# First item added to table lost when visibility toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a function where rows are added from one table to another, but I don't want to display the rows in the second table until at least 2 have been added. However, when I toggle the visibility in this function to 'visible', the first row the user added is not displayed.

```
 const addToFavourites = rowData => {
    let faveRow = document.createElement("tr");

    faveRow.style.visibility='hidden'

    faveRow.innerHTML = 
   `${rowData.innerHTML
    }<td class='cell'><button type='button' 
    class='remove-btn'>Remove</button> . 
    </td>`;

    favesTable.appendChild(faveRow);

   if (favesTable.rows.length > 2) {
    faveRow.style.visibility='visible';
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you only set the visibility of the 3rd row when clicking on it. Loop through your previous rows to set them visible. If you inspect your console in your solution, you'll see that the table row exists, but are still set to `visibility: hidden` and yet you cannot see them.

```js
const favesTable = document.getElementById("favesTable");
const addToFavourites = rowData => {
  let faveRow = document.createElement("tr");

  faveRow.style.visibility='hidden'

  faveRow.innerHTML = 
   `${rowData.innerHTML
    }<td class='cell'><button type='button' 
    class='remove-btn'>Remove</button>
    </td>`;

  favesTable.appendChild(faveRow);

   if (favesTable.rows.length > 2) {
     for(var i = 0; i < favesTable.rows.length; i++) {
      favesTable.rows[i].style.visibility='visible';
     }
   } 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="addToFavourites(this)"><td>Click this row1</td></tr>
  <tr onclick="addToFavourites(this)"><td>Click this row2</td></tr>
  <tr onclick="addToFavourites(this)"><td>Click this row3</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="favesTable"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So simple but somehow I didn't think of it.